# Conflict with using firebase_auth and flutter_localizations packages

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, localization

The packages firebase_auth and flutter_localizations cause the following error. Is there a way to fix this?

```
Because firebase_auth >=0.20.1 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.3 and no versions of firebase_auth match >0.20.0+1 <0.20.1, firebase_auth >0.20.0+1 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.3.
And because firebase_auth 0.20.0+1 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+6, firebase_auth >=0.20.0+1 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 requires firebase_auth_web ^0.3.2+6.
And because firebase_auth_web >=0.3.0-dev.1 <0.4.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on intl ^0.16.1 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0, firebase_auth >=0.20.0+1 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.
So, because geschenk depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and firebase_auth ^0.20.0+1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because geschenk depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and firebase_auth ^0.20.0+1, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by adding the following lines to override the dependencies:

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

My dependencies now look like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.1

dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

Comment: life saviour :)

Comment: What mean this message 'Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:'

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

dependencies:

firebase_auth_web: 0.3.3

firebase_auth: ^0.20.1

flutter:

```
sdk: flutter
```

flutter_localizations:

```
sdk: flutter
```

intl:^0.17.0-nullsafety.2

Answer (score 0):

Remove both

1. firebase_auth
2. intl

dependencies

and add them again

- flutter pub add firebase_auth
- flutter pub add intl